# psycopg2 sql.Identifier fails executing when query is valid

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have a simple psycoph2 snippet which tries to grant usage on a schema but it displays syntax however the query is perfectly valid when executed on the terminal

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import Error, sql, extras, extensions

cursor.execute(sql.SQL("GRANT USAGE on SCHEMA public TO {role}".format(role=sql.Identifier("readonly_role"))))
```

```
Error while connecting to PostgreSQL syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: GRANT USAGE on SCHEMA public TO Identifier('readonly_role')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parens are in the wrong place.

Use `sql.SQL()` on the full raw SQL string, then `.format()` on the result of that (not on the raw string itself).

Here it is broken up and indented for clarity:

```py
cursor.execute(
    sql.SQL(
        "GRANT USAGE on SCHEMA public TO {role}"
    ).format(
        role=sql.Identifier(
            "readonly_role"
        )
    )
)
```